# ASP MVC - sequential enabling logic - does it belong as a model annotation or in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have a group of checkboxes in a page (this is for a clinical randomized control trial screening log, but the principle is as applicable to anything that has a sequence of checkboxes with:

- I certify I have completed step 1 (in this case all inclusion criteria present)
- I certify I have completed step 2 (in this case all exclusion criteria absent)
- ...and so on

each step should be ticked sequentially.
I can write the logic to sequentially enable each checkbox. It seems to me the logic is similar to a validation attribute like [Foolproof validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)'s RequiredIfTrue, and would therefore belong as an attribute on the model property (say EnabledIfTrueAttribute). However, this is also really logic that relates to the display of the information in the browser, and would therefore belong in the view.

Could someone with a clearer understanding of MVC architecture please enlighten me as to which way I should design things and why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of MVC is to separate data, views and the logic that binds them.

Validation attributes are used to validate data that is submitted to the controllers.  How the data is collected is independent of the submission itself.

The view decides how the data will be presented or collected.

Imagine the possibility that some other view may decide to display your options in some other format (such as a dropdown list displaying "how far" the user progressed through your process).

Therefore, in your case...

Validation attributes can be used to ensure that option 4 isn't selected if option 3 is not and reject the submission if that is the case.

How the user selects the options in the model and the enabling/disabling of controls belongs in the view logic.